# what is the difference between 100 and 100px in CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I input

```
    body{
background-size:390 290;
}
```

it shows a different result, whereas, if i input

```
body{
background-size:390px 290px;
}
```

the result is different.
I need to know what's the difference, also why it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Without the px, it's probably a percentage.  To avoid ambiguity, I suggest clarifying those with a percent sign.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: A useful resource: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 4):

100 is not recognized to the browser, so if you type

```
body{
    background-size:390 290;
}
```

It is the same as letting the body style blank

Answer (score 4):

This is CSS:

> ```
> body{
>     background-size:390px 290px;
> }
> ```

---

This is an error:

> ```
> body{
>     background-size:390 290;
> }
> ```

Non-zero lengths **require** units. The CSS specification requires that browsers ignore rules which are invalid.

> why it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

If your page is running in [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) that it will emulate bugs in browsers of the Internet Explorer 4.x era and treat lengths with missing units as pixels.

Don't run pages in quirks mode as it increases inconsistencies between browsers.

Do validate your [CSS](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) and [HTML](https://validator.nu/).

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be  a unit in css ,
100 (without unit) means it will take the default value of body maybe h1  of p  it is not recognized  by css .so you have to put units
Some units:

** PX= The smallest dot it can display measures about 1/100th of an inch (0.25mm) 
**
Other units
1in = 2.54cm = 25.4mm = 72pt = 6pc
**
To understand it more
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp